Spatial index performance
I need help to improve query performance of a spatial query.
I have the following query:
DECLARE @Longitude float,@Latitude float
SET @Longitude = -79.46278668733325
SET @Latitude = 43.70410072435495

SELECT
  GeoLocationBoundary.MakeValid().STCentroid().STDistance(
    geometry::STPointFromText(
      'POINT(' + CAST(@Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326
    )
  ) as DistanceFromCentroid,
  *
FROM App.GeoFence
WHERE GeoLocationBoundary.MakeValid().STIntersects(
  geometry::STPointFromText(
    'POINT(' + CAST(@Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326
  )
) = 1

What Index should I create as the one I created does not seems to be used when running the query.

A rough bounding box as an extra, redundant criteria can often help geospatial queries in sql server.  for example, pre-calculating min/max lat/long values for shapes can allow you to avoid the expensive STIntersects() for points that have no chances of intersecting.
